# fetch result is undefined (Backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, backbone.js, callback

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('hello'),
    initialize: function() {
        var stuff = new FieldCollection();
        var output;
        stuff.parse();
        stuff.fetch({
            success: function (collection, response) {
                console.log(response);
                output=response;
                return response;
             }
        });
        this.render(output);
   },
   render:function(output){
        console.log(output);
        $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>hiii</button>");
        $(this.el).append("<button id='removeAll'>Remove all list item</button>");
    }
});
```

Here I am trying to catch the value of the response in `output` variable... but it's coming up 'undefined'.  Any ideas where I'm mistaken?

Comment: with this information i could deduce loads of problems. Is the server returning proper json? is the server returning anything at all after `fetch`? did you try `console.log(arguments)` inside `success` callback just to make sure you are receiving more than one parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fetch` method is asynchronous, so the `output` variable won't have been assigned by the time you use it.  Try putting the `render` call inside the success-callback instead:

```
var self = this;
stuff.fetch({
        success: function (collection, response) {
            console.log(response);
            output=response;
            self.render(output);
            return response;
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

dbasemans solution is correct considering your setup. However, I would rather bind an event handler to the 'reset' event. This needs to hapen before the fetch. This is cleaner and will also work for further fetches later on in the runtime of your application.